# Gridview text box retuns NULL value upon 'findcontrol'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have a gridview with text box template field added dynamically in code behind, entered value to text box. While fetching the text box value, it's returning empty.

Below code i tried to get value.

'*** I entered "Hello" value in text box control before executing below code.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridviewChild.Rows

            Dim tbSigningGroup As TextBox = DirectCast(row.Cells(4).FindControl("tbSigningGroup" + CStr(row.RowIndex)), TextBox)

            If Not tbSigningGroupIs Nothing Then
                Dim temp As String = tbSigningGroup.Text  ' ****** Returns NULL*******
            End If

Next
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Post your ASPX markup & code behind event (e.g. `RowDataBound`) for clarity. If you're using `ItemTemplate`, just find the textbox on GridView e.g. `DirectCast(row.FindControl("tbSigningGroup" & CStr(row.RowIndex)), TextBox)`.

Comment: Why dont you take the `TextBox` by `column` and `cell` index? Instead of using the name of the control.